# ¿Cómo pasar valor del select en una misma pagina con AJAX?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tengo este código para pasar el valor de un select en una misma pagina, pero estoy pasando el valor del select con **formulario**...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
  <form action="a.php">
  <select name="miselector" id="miselector" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
    <option value="coches">Coches</option>
    <option value="casas">Casas</option>
  </select>
  </form>

 ///Lectura de la variable "en la misma página" desde php

<?php
 echo "Select: ".$_GET["miselector"];
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Habrá alguna manera de pasar valor pero con AJAX, porque no quiero que se cargue la pagina sino que solo se muestre el valor que selecciono en el PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Claro que si hay forma, puedes utilizar jQuery o bien puedes utilizar axios. Te dejo un ejemplo utilizando jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<select name="miselector" id="miselector">
  <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
  <option value="coches">Coches</option>
  <option value="casas">Casas</option>
</select>
```

**JS + JQuery**

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#miselector").on("change", function(){
      var parametros = { // Parametros que vamos a mandar al servidor
        "miselector" : $(this).val() 
      };
      $.ajax({
        data:  parametros, // Adjuntamos los parametros
        url:   'a.php', // ruta del archivo php que procesará nuestra solicitud
        type:  'post', // metodo por el cual se mandarán los datos
        beforeSend: function () { // callback que se ejecutará antes de enviar la solicitud
          console.log("Enviando por medio de post");
        },
        success:  function (response) { // callback que se ejecutará una vez el servidor responda
          console.log("Respuesta del servidor: ", response);
        }
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

** a.php **

```
<?php

$valor = isset($_POST["miselector"]) ? $_POST["miselector"] : false;
if($valor) {
  echo "Recibido valor " + $valor;
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: hola jesus, mi pagina en la cual estoy haciendo todo el codigo es a.php, he tratado de plantear tu codigo pero no ejecuta...

Comment: ¿Que error te dá?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es usar el valor seleccionado en la pagina actual,no es necesario ni PHP ni AJAX. Con una simple funcion JavaScript puedes hacerlo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <body>
      <form action="a.php">
      <select name="miselector" id="miselector"     onchange="document.getElementById('selected_value').innerHTML=this.value">
        <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
        <option value="coches">Coches</option>
        <option value="casas">Casas</option>
      </select>
     </form>
 ///Lectura de la variable "en la misma página" con js
 Selected:
 <div id="selected_value">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDITADO:**
Si necesitas en el mismo fichero tomar el valor y procesarlo con PHP lo puedes hace con AJAX usando JQuery de esta forma

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET["miselector"])){
    echo "INFO PROCESADA EN PHP:".$_GET["miselector"];
}else{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#miselector").on("change", function(){
    $.get("a.php?miselector="+this.value,function(result){
        $("#returned").html(result);
    });
  });
 });
</script>
</head>
    <body>
    <form action="a.php">
     <select name="miselector" id="miselector">
        <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
        <option value="coches">Coches</option>
        <option value="casas">Casas</option>
    </select>
    </form>

<div id="returned">
    aqui cambiara el contenido seleccionado
</div>

 </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: si es necesario, ya que ese valor me servira para poder hacer una consulta(a la base de datos) en un nuevo select, para tener unos options relacionados al primer select

Comment: te puse un ejemplo como en el mismo fichero php puedes hacer lo que quieres usando ajax aunque no es recomendable hacerlo de esta forma